# How to use MSTEST with Visual Studio 11 Dev Preview?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Exactly as the question says :

How can I MSTEST with Visual Studio 11 Dev Preview ?

I tried to find the mstest.exe but it doesnt exist in its usual location :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

I wrote some unit tests and there is no way to run them =\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSTest has never been part of the Express editions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

`MSTest.exe` is present on my PC in the specified location.

OTOH, if you just started writing the tests, you may want to look at [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/), some of the reasons being posted here: [Why I'm migrating from MSTest to xUnit.net](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/WhyImMigratingFromMSTestToXUnitnet.aspx).

For VS11 there is a runner available as an extension: [Prototype xUnit.net Visual Studio 11 Unit Testing Plugin](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/09/prototype-xunitnet-visual-studio-11-unit-testing-plugin.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Darin Dimitrov answered, MSTest is not available in Express edition, and you should install the Ultimate edition from here,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/hh127353